# Specific Annual Examination Marks

Tags: elementary-number-theory, factoring, prime-factorization

Steve has recently got his annual exam result.He has got upper than 690 out of 750.His obtained marks has odd number of factors.What is his obtained marks?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** The positive integer $n$ has an odd number of factors if and only if $n$ is a perfect square.

**Remark:** You have probably seen a proof of the above fact. If you have not, if $uv=n$ and $u\ne v$, call the pair $\{u,v\}$ a **couple**, or, to be more modern, **partners**.

If $n$ is not a perfect square, the divisors of $n$ break up into partner pairs, so there is an even number of divisors. If $n$ is a perfect square $m^2$, then the divisor $m$ of $n$ remains unpartnered, so we get the partnered people (even total number) plus the unpartnered  one, so the number of divisors is odd.

Work out the details for say $n=12$ and $n=36$. For each one, write down the couples. (For $36$, the divisor $6$ remains uncoupled.) Now you will know the **why** of the result forever.

Comment: That still leaves two possibilities, but I don't see how we tell between them.

Comment: One cannot. Maybe a mistake in the question, maybe something about the marking scheme that we have not been told (all marks are even?).